# Reshaping MNIST for ResNet50

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist, resnet

I am trying to train the mnist dataset on ResNet50 using the `Keras` library.
The shape of mnist is `(28, 28, 1)` however resnet50 required the shape to be `(32, 32, 3)`

How can I convert the mnist dataset to the required shape?

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2], 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], x_test.shape[2], 1)
x_train = x_train/255.0
x_test = x_test/255.0
```

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)
```

```
model = models.Sequential()
# model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(28, 28)))
# model.add(Reshape(target_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
# model.add(Conv2D())
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=20, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer sequential_10: expected shape=(None, 32, 32, 3), found shape=(20, 28, 28, 1)
```

Comment: ResNet50 requires RGB images whereas MNIST is grayscale, you should convert the data to RGB first.

Comment: Note that reshape and resize are NOT the same thing, you need to resize images, not reshape them (as your title suggests).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to resize the `MNIST` data set. Note that minimum size actually depends on the ImageNet model. For example: `Xception` requires at least `72`, where `ResNet` is asking for `32`.  Apart from that, the `MNIST` is a grayscale image, but it may conflict if you're using the pretrained weight of these models. So, good and safe side is to resize and convert grayscale to **RGB**.

---

Full working code for you.

**Data Set**

We will resize `MNIST` from 28 to 32. Also, make 3 channels instead of keeping 1.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 

(x_train, y_train), (_, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# expand new axis, channel axis 
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1)

# [optional]: we may need 3 channel (instead of 1)
x_train = np.repeat(x_train, 3, axis=-1)

# it's always better to normalize 
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255

# resize the input shape , i.e. old shape: 28, new shape: 32
x_train = tf.image.resize(x_train, [32,32]) # if we want to resize 

# one hot 
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train , num_classes=10)

print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
```

```
(60000, 32, 32, 3) (60000, 10)
```

**ResNet 50**

```
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32,32,3))
efnet = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet',
                                             include_top = False, 
                                             input_tensor = input)
# Now that we apply global max pooling.
gap = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(efnet.output)

# Finally, we add a classification layer.
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', use_bias=True)(gap)

# bind all
func_model = tf.keras.Model(efnet.input, output)
```

**Train**

```
func_model.compile(
          loss  = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
          metrics = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(),
          optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
# fit 
func_model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=5, verbose = 2)
```

```
Epoch 1/5
469/469 - 56s - loss: 0.1184 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9690
Epoch 2/5
469/469 - 21s - loss: 0.0648 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9844
Epoch 3/5
469/469 - 21s - loss: 0.0503 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 4/5
469/469 - 21s - loss: 0.0416 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9888
Epoch 5/5
469/469 - 21s - loss: 0.1556 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9697
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f316005a3d0>
```

Comment: Thanks! What machine/environment are you using? The code is taking a very long time to run on Google Colab.

Comment: You should instead use [`tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/Resizing) inside the model to avoid holding the entire 60,000 + 10,000 resized images in memory. *Edit:* that might not be as important as I thought since you're only rescaling from 28 to 32

Comment: @OmkarVedak I used colab too. Maybe you were in CPU mode.

Comment: @M.Innat I tried your proposed code but I got the following error : **TypeError: Type of `metrics` argument not understood. Expected a list or dictionary, found: <tensorflow.python.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy object at 0x7f127a3ff0f0>**

Comment: If possible, please share a broken colab link.